# Sitecore media conversion tool not installing

Tags: sitecore, sitecore6, sitecore-media-library

Or, alternately, I'm not doing something right.  I install this module (http://trac.sitecore.net/MediaConversionTool/#), but then visits to

```
http://localhost/sitecore modules/media conversion tool
```

return a Sitecore 404 (the page you get when the Sitecore handler doesn't know what to do with your request).  I've made sure that /sitecore modules/media conversion tool is in the IgnoreURLPrefixes list.  What else would I be missing?

This tool is supposed to help migrate files from app_data into the database, and vice versa.  I don't think, though, that the issue is with the tool.  It's with the install, I think, and I'm guessing that there's some step I haven't covered.  This is the first time I've tried to install a sitecore package.

Comment: Martijn's answer details the correct approach for accessing this tool

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Media Conversion Tool is installed as a Sitecore application. You should open it from inside the Sitecore client under the start-button -> all applications -> Media conversion tool.
As it is a XAML application, it can't be openend through the url you are using.

Comment: Worked perfectly.  Feeling foolish.  :-)